# Write to an existing xml file (python 3)

Tags: xml, python-3.x, elementtree

i am new to python. Still learning :) I learned how to parse trough an xml document (pull out some data). Now i want to change data in xml file. For example: change the description of a movie or rating. For parsing trough the xml i am using:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
```

xml file named watched.xml:

```
<collection shelf="My collection">
<movie title="Enemy Behind">
   <type>War, Thriller</type>
   <format>DVD</format>
   <year>2003</year>
   <imdb>9</imdb>
   <description>Talk about a US-Japan war</description>
</movie>
<movie title="Transformers">
   <type>Anime, Science Fiction</type>
   <format>DVD</format>
   <year>1989</year>
   <imdb>8</imdb>
   <description>A schientific fiction</description>
</movie>
<series title="game of thrones">
    <season titler="Winter Is Coming">
       <type> Adventure, Drama, Fantasy</type>
       <format>DVD</format>
       <episode>1</episode>
       <imdb>9.5</imdb>
       <description>Niceeeee!</description>
    </season>
    <season title="The Kingsroad">
       <type> Adventure, Drama, Fantasy</type>
       <format>DVD</format>
       <episode>2</episode>
       <imdb>9.0</imdb>
       <description>Niceee again</description>
    </season>
</series>>
</collection>
```

Comment: Please paste the code you have problems with

Comment: I dont have code. i am searching for advice, or example